# Python install location on OSX - trouble installing python modules

Tags: python, macos

I'm having a problem installing python packages and I think it has to do with the fact that I apparently have 4 Python directories. I can download and install them without a problem using pip... but when trying to import them in an IDE they don't appear.

Any help would be appreciated and I should say that I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: If you find out which python executable your IDE is using, you can install packages specifically with that one.  For example if your IDE uses `/usr/bin/python`, you can use `/usr/bin/python -m pip install ...`

Comment: as an alternative you can run your python from terminal.

Comment: I know I needed to explicitly use `pip3.5`/`pip2.7` because just using `pip` and `python` seemed to be using different versions.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really tricky issue specific to OS X, and also hard to fix. The root cause is the fact the GUI apps and console apps do not share the same environment (with things like PATH and PYTHONPATH).

Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/99834